# R: ifelse statement to assign a value to another column

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, operators

Based on three conditions I want to assign the value 1. The following code works if I use only one `&` (so for example leave out 2018).

```
df[df$2017 == 1 & 
   df$2018 == 0 &
   df$x == -1, ]$y <- 1
```

I believe an ifelse statements is what I need, but I don't understand how to assign value `1` to column `y` within the statement.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to subset the 'y' with the logical vector instead of subsettng the whole dataset and then extracting the column

```
df$y[with(df, `2017` == 1 & 
                  `2018` == 0 &
                    x == -1)] <- 1
```

If we need to use multiple values, change the `==` to `%in%`

```
df$y[with(df, `2017` == 1 & 
                  `2018` == 0 &
                    x == -1 &
                  `2019` %in% c(0, 1))] <- 1
```

Comment: I get the following error: in `*tmp*`$y: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Did a really quick search but not a very easy solution it seems. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Marc-Marijn can you check your `str(df)` is it a data.frame or matrix

Comment: how would it work when year `2019` should be able to take both values (1 and 0) in the same line of code?

Comment: @Marc-Marijn use `%in% `2019` %in% c(0, 1)`

Comment: I see! could you show me where I implement this inside the code? Very thankful for your help Akrun